Scanpy Neighborhood Graph Construction Error: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'"
I am running a standard scanpy workflow on a dataset and I reached the neighborhood graph construction.
When I run the line:
sc.pp.neighbors(adata, n_neighbors=10, n_pcs=11)
I get the following error:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
I have followed the workflow from https://scanpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/basics/clustering.html#clustering and this is the first time I have encountered this issue. I am fairly new to scanpy so I'm not sure how to fix this. If it helps, I am running this on Jupyter Notebook, I'm using scanpy version 1.10.2 and anndata version 0.10.8.
I tried changing the n_pcs and run it but that didn't work. I also restarted the kernel and reran it to see if it would work but it didn't.

Please provide a [example].

First, you need to provide the full stacktrace that the error is at the end of. Please read How do I ask a good question?. There it emphasizes to include any error messages as text. (Additional support: "We need to see all, and the verbatim error messages" Source.) If you have very long code or error to share you can use a gist or other code/snipper sharing service.  ... Beyond that...Maybe a step back here is a good idea? And/orr let us know about your experience/environment?  ...

 If you run the tutorial example with the provided data entirely the sc.pp.neighbors() step works? Or does it give this error? If you change the code in the tutorial from sc.pp.neighbors(adata) to sc.pp.neighbors(adata, n_neighbors=10, n_pcs=11) it works? Or gives the error? We don't have access to your data & so we need to know if it is your environment or data at this point. With a fresh environment with scanpy 1.10.2, the tutorial (with tutorial data) for that step and changing it to your version of that step worked. So if it works for the tutorial in your environment...

 then it is something about your data.
